# JQUERY: Multiplying input elements select box and radio boxes and hidden inputs

Tags: jquery

Evening,

I'm tyring to multiply different input elements but for some reason it's giving me a NAND error. As the user selects, check or modify the values of any element. This should change the total amount.

http://jsfiddle.net/aQ5K8/

```
<select name="select">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input name="radio" type="radio" id="radio" value="10" tvalue="100" />
<input name="radio" type="radio" id="radio" value="20" tvalue="200" />
<label id="Total"></label>
```

Also if you take a look at the jsfiddle code i have tvalue=100 and the other is =200 as a custom attributes, how would I access that instead of accessing the regular html value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

typo: make sure your ID you use as jquery selector is correct. i see `id="amazon25"` and selector is `$("#amazon5")` and the other 2 elements. perhaps you mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/bondythegreat/2Pzyz/

Comment: throw in that there is no `id=select` either

Comment: Got it fixed http://jsfiddle.net/463R7/ except now  the calculation get screwed when i change select box after picking a radio

Answer (score 0):

Well, check this jsFiddle, it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/aQ5K8/5/

The problem as with `name` instead of `id` in html and `amazon5` instead of `amazon25` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the below link

http://jsfiddle.net/aQ5K8/

we will get the following issue

1. select element not having id as "select" and so $("#select") won't return the element.
   2.Similarly in below code the there is no element with id amazon5,cash5

   ```
   var amazon5= parseFloat$('#amazon5').val();
   var cash5 = parseFloat($('#cash5').val());
   ```

We suggest you to refer the below code

HTML

```
<select name="select" id="select">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Script

```
$("input[type=radio][name=radio]").click(function() {
var quantity = parseFloat($(this).val());
var amazon5= parseFloat($('#amazon25').val());
var cash5 = parseFloat($('#cash25').val());
var radio = $(this).val();  
var select = parseFloat($('#select').val());
$('#Total').text((select * radio * amazon5));

});
```

Refer the link for more information
http://jsfiddle.net/bondythegreat/2Pzyz/

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kUaPX/ working with custom attribute instead of regular value. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.